# mysql : InnoDB: Cannot continue operation

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql on windows 7 environment.
When I attempt to start the server from command line 
as: mysqld --user=root

I get following message:

```
120914 15:47:04 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\SFO1502128830A.lower-test
120914 15:47:04 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\SFO1502128830A.lower-test
120914 15:47:04 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120914 15:47:04 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120914 15:47:04 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
120914 15:47:04 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120914 15:47:04 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120914 15:47:04 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120914 15:47:04  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory. It may also be you have created a subdirectory
InnoDB: of the same name as a data file.
InnoDB: File name .\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Please advice,
Thanks,

Comment: What part of `The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory` don't you understand? The user MySQL is running under doesn't have the required permissions in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\ which is what Windows 7 [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) will be the cause of. Easiest fix: Move your data directory to something like `d:\mysqldata` or similar.

Comment: Its likely that you need to start via admin privilege

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
Run Windows CMD Prompt as an Administrator and execute your MySql command.

Comment: This is the answer